# Scripts conflict

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The scripts are working on the first load. However,when I select on the dropdown and the page will reload for the new data on the table based on what I have selected that's the time I won't be able to gather the data when I click in a row. See code below:

> code.gs

```
function doGet()
{
  var html=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  return html.evaluate();
}

function getSelect() {
  var list = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadssheetID').getSheetByName("VL Slots").getDataRange().getValues();
  var lane = 1;
  var select="";
  for (var l = 3; l < list.length; l++) {
    select+='<option value="' + list[l][lane] + '">'+ list[l][lane] + ' </option>';
  }
  return select;
}
function getTable(lob) {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadssheetID').getSheetByName("VL Request").getDataRange().getValues();
  var rid = 0;
  var request = 1;
  var table="";
  table+='<tr>';
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { 
    if (data[i][rid] == lob) {
      table+='<td>' + data[i][request] + '</td>';
    }
  }
  table+='</tr>';
  return  table;
}
```

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">
      </head>
      <script>
      function populateSelect(){
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getSelect();
       }
      function onSuccess(select){
        document.getElementById("mySelect").innerHTML=select;
      }
      function polling(){
        setInterval(myFunction,2000);
       }
      function myFunction(){
        var lob = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess2).getTable(lob);    

      }
      function onSuccess2(table){
        document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML=table;
      }
      </script>
      <body onload="populateSelect()">
        <select id="mySelect" onchange="polling()">
        </select>
        <table id="myTable">
        </table>
<form id="logForm">
<label>Request <span class="required">*</span></label><input type="text" id="request" name="request" class="field-long" placeholder="Request" readonly /> 
</form>

<script>

                var table = document.getElementById('myTable');

                for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
                {
                    table.rows[i].onclick = function()
                    {
                         //rIndex = this.rowIndex;
             document.getElementById("request").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML.trim();

                    };
                }

         </script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

What I want to happen is that I can select on the dropdown and the data will be gathered on the table based on what I have selected and I can click on the row to pass the information in the form.

Comment: Your new table doesn't have click handlers.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You want request to be a user input that is evaluated by the script and returns the column specified by input?

Answer (score 0):

- If I understood correctly, your goal is to click on the value retrieved from the spreadsheet by polling and set this value as a content of your input field "request".
- If this is the case, you should incorporate your request inside the `onSuccess2` function, so it will occur after the table has been populated with contents from the spreadsheet
- Keep in mind that since you retrieve only one value from the sheet, you do not need to loop through row
- Modify the html part of your code as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <script>
  function populateSelect(){
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getSelect();
   }
  function onSuccess(select){
    document.getElementById("mySelect").innerHTML=select;
  }
  function polling(){
    setInterval(myFunction,2000);
   }
  function myFunction(){
    var lob = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess2).getTable(lob);        
  }
  function onSuccess2(table){
    document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML=table;
    var myTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
    var row = myTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
    var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    var request= cell.innerHTML;
    row.onclick = createClickHandler(request); 
  }  
  var createClickHandler = function(request) {
    return function(){
      document.getElementById("request").value = request;
    };      
  }        
  </script>
  <body onload="populateSelect()">
    <select id="mySelect" onchange="polling()">
    </select>
    <table id="myTable">
    </table>    
    <form id="logForm">
      <label>Request <span class="required">*</span></label><input type="text" id="request" name="request" class="field-long" placeholder="Request" readonly  /> 
    </form>       
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if there are more than one td and input involved?

Comment: For creating a second input field , just give it a different id and define e.g. `var lob2 = document.getElementById("mySelect2").value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess3).getTable(lob2);`  And `function onSuccess3(table){ ...
    var row = myTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
    var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
...
  }` If you have many inputs, you should implement a `for` loop and counter variables to address the right cell - e.g `var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[i];`